# log4j rolling file (logs application)

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, catalina

I have web application (struts2), and I want to manage the logs.

When I use

```
<appender name="dailyLog" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/test.log" />
                <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <param name="Append" value="true"/>
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="2KB"/>
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] %-30c{1} %x: %m\n"/>
                </layout>
        </appender>
```

I have a rolling of file, but I have tomcat.out that contains a application logs.

When I use `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`, I don't have  rolling logs but I have catalina.out static (logs of start, stop of tomcat only)

```
<appender name="dailyLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/test.log" />
                <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <param name="Append" value="true"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] %-30c{1} %x: %m\n"/>
                </layout>
        </appender>
```

My question is: Can we have rotation of logs file + catalina.out (that contains only logs of restart of tomcat server)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to roll over **catalina.out** file you need to use different approach since this requires a Tomcat restart. If your server deployed on a Unix/Linux machine you should consider to use logrotate or similar program.

In general, application logs directory should be in different place than your container logs.